# How do I make my Discord Bot make a message right after it's launched?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

Ok so basically what I'm trying to say is that I watched a few tutorials online on how to make a discord bot (but ya know, I'm not really that good at it) and I was wondering you guys can help me with this SIMPLE problem.

For example:
If the bot updates, when the bot comes back online, it outputs a custom message saying its updated. For the most part, I want to understand how to make it so the bot says a message in a channel after I make it come online. Thanks!

BOT SOURCE CODE
https://ghostbin.com/paste/q2doq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the client onReady handler.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
  //Or Something else
  var channelToSend = client.channels.get('ID');
  channelToSend.send("test");
});
```